# possible null assignment in Dictionary Contains Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

Getting a warning on "!redirectsDictionary.ContainsKey(autoRedirect.Key)"

asp.net possible null assignment to entity marked with "notnull" attribute.

Just wondering what that's about ?

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Redirect> AutoRedirectsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Redirect>();

foreach (var r in db.SelectItems("fast:/sitecore/content/Redirects Root//*[@@templatename='Auto Redirect']"))
        {
            GenerateRedirects(Context.Database.GetItem(r.Fields["Root Node"].Value), r["URL Prefix"]);
            foreach (var autoRedirect in AutoRedirectsDictionary)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(autoRedirect.Key) & !redirectsDictionary.ContainsKey(autoRedirect.Key))
                {
                    //Add to dictionary
                    redirectsDictionary.Add(autoRedirect.Key, autoRedirect.Value);
                }

            }
        }

public static void GenerateRedirects(Item redirectFolder, string urlPrefix)
        {
            if (redirectFolder == null)
                return;

            var childList = redirectFolder.GetChildren();

            foreach (Item child in childList)
            {
                if (Utilities.HasFieldValue(child, FieldToFind))
                {
                    var shortcutUrl = urlPrefix + child.Fields[FieldToFind].Value.ToLower();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shortcutUrl) && !AutoRedirectsDictionary.ContainsKey(shortcutUrl))
                    {
                        AutoRedirectsDictionary.Add(shortcutUrl,
                        new Redirect(String.Empty, child, true));       
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GenerateRedirects(child, urlPrefix);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what line are you getting that warning on ? Warnings don't always mean there is a issue

Comment: In this line  !redirectsDictionary.ContainsKey(autoRedirect.Key) there is a warning under autoRedirect.Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have to do with your use of the single `&` operator.  A single `&` will not use short-circuiting to bypass a statement but will instead choose the path to execute after all expressions have been evaluated.  So even though you're checking `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(autoRedirect.Key)` prior to the ContainsKey call, both expressions will be evaluated first and then the path of execution will be decided.

Edited as I realized I didn't truly answer your specific question (and you may already know this) but `!redirectsDictionary.ContainsKey(autoRedirect.Key)` will throw an exception if the key is null.  Since the datatype for the key is a `string` there is a possibility it will throw an exception if it is null, hence the warning.